# Assign php variable to javascript with AJAX

Tags: php

I use AJAX to call a php script. From within php I need to update a JavaScript variable:

```
<script>cf = <?php echo $cf; ?>;</script>
```

It seems that when JavaScript is generated asynchronously in this way, nothing in JavaScript is updated.

Here is the code as requested by Rainmx93.

The PHP code:

```
<?php
$inr = str_replace( ',', '.',  $_POST[ 'inr' ] );
$cf = 0;    // will be passed to a JavaScript global variable

$decrStr =  '
<h3>Some text</h3>
';

if ( $inr <= 0 ) {  // string is evaluated by php as 0
    echo '<p>Some Error message.</p>';
} 
elseif ( $inr < 1.5 ) {
    $cf = -2;
    echo '<p class="my-red-box">Some feedback.</p>' . $decrStr;
}

?>

<script>
cf = <?php echo $cf; ?>;
</script>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
var form_data = "inr=1";


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/backend/filename.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var result = this.responseText;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
xhr.send(form_data);
```

Comment: you need to update `cf` in ajax success function

Comment: Can you please add a sample code?

Comment: yes i can but please paste in question your php and ajax code

Comment: I have updated the question with some of the actual code .

Comment: Just add quotes... I’ll work

Comment: Change it to `cf = ‘<?php echo $cf; ?>`

Answer (score -1):

use JSON to parse data from php to script

example :

```
    <?php 
    $var = "something";
    ?>
    <script>
    var new = <?php json_encode($var); ?>;

    </script>

    <?php 
//Something can be here 

?>
```

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @ Shirantha: I thought of making PHP return the data in a JSON format but as my PHP skills are quite rudimentary, I doubt I could achieve this by myself. Your example is similar to my approach, but JavaScript generated in PHP by an AJAX call doesn't seem to work. The question however is it possible to modify JavaScript via asynchronously accessed PHP?

Comment: @SamoZaparola you are trying to say that, you are sending a variable (as a post data) to a PHP file, and this particular php file has this script which needs the said variable to perform it's function ?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript sends some form data to PHP, PHP processes it and a div tag is updated as a result. What I want additionally is JavaScript to get access to the PHP processed data for some subsequent JavaScript functions depend on it.

Comment: @SamoZaparola, noted. First Check whether the data has been received to this Php File. ( you can use print_r or var_dump to see that). If the data has been received, then assign them to your variable (like. `var= $_POST['variablename']; `)  once it is assigned, use the `JSON` to pass that data to your script.

Comment: Yes, the $_POST array is working as expected. Can you provide an example how this particular JSON is to be constructed in PHP - to return both text and a value of a variable, and how to request and receive it in JavaScript?

Comment: once you send the `POST request` if your url goes as `something.php?abc=123` then simply use 'GET` to capture the data sent from first file to second php file. then assign that value to a variable. example `var=$_GET['abc']`. then use `JSON` to pass this data to your script.